# Some errors while installing Chocolatey

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll, chocolatey

I'm currently trying to download Jekyll on Windows 10, and I'm having difficulty installing Ruby through Chocolatey. I'm following the instructions provided on this website:https://jekyllrb.com/docs/windows/

Here is the error that is causing some trouble. I have entered choco install ruby -version 2.2.4 and it gave me this error:

```
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading ruby 2.2.4... 100%
ruby not installed. An error occurred during installation:
 Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\ruby\tools' is denied.
ruby package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
This is try 1/3. Retrying after 300 milliseconds.
 Error converted to warning:
 Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey' is denied.
This is try 2/3. Retrying after 400 milliseconds.
 Error converted to warning:
 Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey' is denied.
Maximum tries of 3 reached. Throwing error.
Cannot create directory "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey". Error was:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at chocolatey.infrastructure.filesystem.DotNetFileSystem.<>c__DisplayClass64.<create_directory>b__63()
   at chocolatey.infrastructure.tolerance.FaultTolerance.<>c__DisplayClass1.<retry>b__0()
   at chocolatey.infrastructure.tolerance.FaultTolerance.retry[T](Int32 numberOfTries, Func`1 function, Int32 waitDurationMilliseconds, Int32 increaseRetryByMilliseconds, Boolean isSilent)
   at chocolatey.infrastructure.filesystem.DotNetFileSystem.create_directory(String directoryPath)
   at chocolatey.infrastructure.filesystem.DotNetFileSystem.create_directory_if_not_exists(String directoryPath, Boolean ignoreError)
Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey' is denied.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the installation program with administrator rights. The error shows that the access to the directory `programData` is denied!

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, since you run in windows cmd, run the `cmd.exe` as Administrator. Then, continue `choco install ruby`